# valve's SOURCE loading screen

Tags: html, echo, steam

```
<div class="userDet">
        <?php 
            echo "Welcome to the server, $steamid! </br>"
            echo "Map: $map</br>"
            echo "Enjoy your stay." 
        ?>
    </div>
```

while this works loading it up locally, when i connect to it on my webiste i get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ':' in /home/u272437591/public_html/yes.html on line 29
```

Website:http://justin-wood.tk/yes.html
if you want the full html code just ask

Comment: You forgot the ; at the end of line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put semicolons

```
<div class="userDet">
        <?php 
            echo "Welcome to the server, $steamid! </br>";
            echo "Map: $map</br>";
            echo "Enjoy your stay.";
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @rekire, why is that? Not saying you're wrong, just out of curiosity -- Yazan's answer is the correct solution to OP's question after all...